# ruby on rails: search through user emails in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

By clicking a button in my app, a user can 'invite' another person to join up. The email contacts in their address book are scanned and they can click from the list who they want to send an email to.

At present the screen looks something like this:
[image]

Basically, I want to have 'Already using by cool app!' only if the email in the person's address book is already present in my database. Any idea how to do this?

A user's email is identified in my database as @user.email. I know what I have to do is, 'scan through all the @user.emails in my database and if they match @contact.name then show the message', but not sure how to code it.

The relevant part of my code is:

```
<!-- go through all the contacts in a person's email address book -->
 <% @contacts.each do |name, value| %>
        <div class="email">
<!-- for all the contacts, have a check box, unchecked -->
          <%= check_box_tag "contacts[]", value, false, :id => value %>
<!-- make a label with the check box and the person's email
          <label for="<%= value %>"><%= name %></label>
          <%= "Already using my cool app!" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if !User.find_by_email(mail_address).nil?
```

should do the trick

if you want to avoid making a lot of individual db calls you could fetch an array of all the mail addresses of all users first and then just check if it `user.include?(mail_address)`

or

use `where(:email => array_of_contac_mail_addresses)` to get a limited set and just check a match there

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for that! I changed your code above to 'if !User.find_by_email(name).nil?' and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
User.where(:email => email).exists?
```

To avoid multiple db queries, u can first fetch the emails like

```
existing_emails = User.where(["email IN (?)", @contacts.map(&:email)]).map &:email
```

and

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  ..
  <% if existing_emails.include?(contact.email) %>

  <% else %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Neo, thanks for that. I'll look into your code and see how it works. The answer below also talks about, 'To avoid multiple db queries...' Just want to know why it matters? I imagine it's because it takes up server resources/slows down your application? At the moment I'm working in localhost mode, but maybe when it's online and things get busy it would start to matter. Any way you could measure the difference - use of multiple calls vs just one call?

Comment: Yes, it does slow down the application. You could do some basic benchmarks using Time.now later if you want to test if the difference in performance matters to you -> 'before = Time.now; your code; after = Time.now - before; puts after' or something like that